# Cascode Datasheet Capacitances

Tags: cascode

Cascode devices used in power systems are assigned values for Ciss, Coss and Crss in the datasheet, for example the UF3C120150K4S ( https://unitedsic.com/datasheets/DS_UF3C120150K4S.pdf )

What does this mean in terms of the capacitances of the low voltage mosfet and high voltage jfet used within the cascode?

Below is a description of the capacitances I found at 2 different operating conditions, would the datasheet values be a description at one of these conditions? If so which one?

[image]

Comment: Fig 13 shows all the conditions for Vds in the datasheet thus both apply from above Fig is 6

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks Tony that makes sense